# SEO Single Page Applictaion

Tags: html, seo, anchor

i like singlepages with anchors but i have seen, that site:domain.com only show one result on google.

my sections are like

```
<div id="section">content...</div>
```

and my links are like:

```
<a href="#section">section link</a>
```

is there a way to build the singlepage a other way to get a result for each section? i dont like to use any frameworks...

Comment: Is all the content in the HTML, and you're just using standard anchor links to scroll to it? Or is there an AJAX script at work?

Comment: all the content is inside the html. only using javascript for smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way now is to pre-render the website on your server, using something like PhantomJS and serve the result to the Google crawler. Creating a sitemap can also help.

Answer (score 0):

With no URL change and all the content in the HTML document - Google will only see one page.

Google indexes complete web pages. It will not separately list anchor links to the *same page*.

Either split your document into multiple pages or paginate content using different URLs.

Comment: i've already tried changing the URL using `history.replaceState({}, "", newUrl)` to the right anchorlink. but google is still listing only one page.

Comment: what do u mean with "paginate content using different URLs"? could you explain it more clearly using an example? :)

Comment: You need to create a unique URL that downloads just the content you want indexed. Google is not going to present the same HTML doc to a user through different URLs. You can either split them into pages - or have AJAX requests present new content depending on the query string. There are lots of checks and balances within Google to stop you duplicating content (different URL, same content served) and you won't circumvent them with just a simple switch. A hashbang #! (sometimes called a shebang) is another method that might work for a one-page doc.